# Use PowerApp to enter the user's input into the word document.

Tags: powerapps

I am working on Powerapp and need to create an application where on basis of user's selection, we will choose a word document and then populate user's input value in it. For example. If a user chooses year as 2018 then a document belonging to this year will be selected and the user will fill a form whose values will get populated inside the word document. I know we have quick parts for this but I need to achieve it through PowerApp.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best choice in this case is to use a combination of PowerApps and [Flow](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Here are the instructions on how to trigger a flow from a PowerApp:

> **Start a flow in a canvas app**
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/using-logic-flows

See the following article on how to use a flow connector to update a Word document using a document template. (*The latest version of the connector seems to have changed the APIs, so there may be some work to do instead of simply following the instructions in the article.*)

> **Create DOCX Word document from template based on dynamic data in Microsoft Flow**
>   https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community-Blog/Create-DOCX-Word-document-from-template-based-on-dynamic-data-in/ba-p/79389

Comment: Is there any other free connector available for this as Plumsail is licensed one?